# How can I multiply an integer by negative two by only using bitwise operators in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

For an assignment, I need to replicate the effects of the C representation of (-2 * x) by only using binary operators of ( ! ~ & ^ | + << >> ). This means no use of loops, if statements, etc. We can assume the system uses 2's complement and a 32 bit representation of integers, performs right shifts arithmetically, and has unpredictable behavior when shifting an integer by more than the word size.

A quick solution that worked but wasn't passable was to return -(x<<1); as I know shifting right is multiplication, but I cant use the negative operator. Can't really think of another solution logically.

Comment: Yes, in the directions it says we can assume our machine uses 2's complement, 32-bit representations of integers

Comment: Are you allowed to use addition `(+)`?

Comment: yes, addition is included as one of the allowed operators for this one

Comment: Then left shift it to multiply by 2 and then make it negative by applying the 2s complement operation (invert and then plus 1). This feels like a trick question to see if you remember what 2s complement means.

Comment: `~(n << 1) + 1`, calculate multiplication with `+2`, get 1's complement and add one.

Comment: @slebetman Thank you all for the help in such a fast and timely manner, really appreciate it as I am new to the C language and coding as a whole!

Comment: @alex01011 Thank you all for the help in such a fast and timely manner, really appreciate it as I am new to the C language and coding as a whole!

Comment: Lee Humingh, next time try `-2 * x`, enable all optimizations, compile  and report the emitted assembly code.  **That* may show a very speed alternative without `*`.  Let the compiler be your friend.

Answer (score 3):

As slebetman and alex01011 mentioned, I just needed to left shift x by one to account for the multiplication, but then invert it and add one to make it negative.

So it would look like:

~(x << 1) + 1.

Thank you all for the help in such a fast and timely manner, really appreciate it as I am new to the C language and coding as a whole!

Comment: `~(x << 1) + 1` does not have _defined behavior_.  It is UB to shift into the sign bit.  Perform shift with `uint32_t` math instead.